# Specs2 version 4 - how to use Future matchers (such as `awaitFor`)

Tags: specs2

Upon upgrading to specs2 version 4, our tests which were using Future matchers started to fail.

This is what those tests look like:

```
class SomeSpec(implicit ee: ExecutionEnv) extends Specification {
  "some spec" should {
    "check some async thing" in {
      val asyncThing = ... // calls test subject 
      asyncThing must beEqualTo("some value").awaitFor(10.seconds)
    }
  }
}
```

I can see mentions of breaking changes to future matchers in this blog post:
http://etorreborre.blogspot.com.au/2017/08/specs2-4x.html

But it's not clear to me what I need to change to make the tests pass (or whether there is a solution at all)

The user guides on specs2 website don't seem to have been updated either.

Comment: Can you please say in which way it is failing? Would you have a test project where I could observe this? Also thanks for pointing out that the user guide hasn't been updated. I worked on that today and I hope to publish tomorrow once I figured out how to produced a unified API now that specs2 is on Scala.js

Comment: Also you shouldn't have to change anything in that code above, so there might be an issue with the latest version.

Comment: The site, the user guide and the scaladoc are now up-to-date.

Comment: I'm getting timeout errors (same tests used to pass with specs2 version "3.9.5"):

Timeout after 10 seconds (retries = 0, timeout = 10 seconds), timeFactor = 1 (SomeSpec.scala:5)

Comment: There could be some contention somewhere, I would like to investigate, would you have a project showing the issue? Also something you can try is to use the OwnExecutionEnv trait: `class MySpec(val env: Env) extends Specification with OwnExecutionEnv`. This will bring an implicit ExecutionEnv just for that specification.

Comment: Thanks Eric for your replies.

I've  created this test project to demonstrate the issue:
https://github.com/mmollaverdi/specs2-v4-future-matchers-issue

Turns out the example I provided in the initial question was actually too simplistic. It doesn't fail with only a single test. It's a bit strange, but it actually passes even with 2 test files as long as one of them only has one test case in it. Adding another test case to a second test file makes all the tests fail.

See my commit messages for more details:
https://github.com/mmollaverdi/specs2-v4-future-matchers-issue/commits/master

Comment: I'll try the `OwnExecutionEnv` trait next to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: OK, `OwnExecutionEnv` fixes the issue:
https://github.com/mmollaverdi/specs2-v4-future-matchers-issue/commit/b6369fe30d7bd2abbe107a25b6468a808b084724

Can you verify that, this commit is how it's intended to be used please? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this small project. I was actually able to reproduce all the time by setting the threadsnb argument to 1. I will publish a fix in 4.0.1 over the week-end. This way you will not need `OwnExecutionEnv`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Eric

Comment: For now I have published `4.0.1-2c0d6d9-20171014100524` for scala 2.12 if you want to try it.

Comment: `4.0.1` is available now

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: don't change anything but your specs2 version where the fix is :-). This issue is fixed in specs2 4.0.1.